# Why does an attempt to use mark() and reset() on FileInputStream generate an IOException?

Tags: java

I am trying to understand how the implementation of `mark()` and `reset()` is done to be capable to override it on `ByteArrayInputStream` and other classes but not on Class `FileInputStream`. We know that both classes extend abstract Class `InputStream` which is the parent for both methods. This are not final methods since we can use them on Class `ByteArrayInputStream`. What technique is used to prevent `FileInputStream` from overriding other methods but not these two ie. `mark()` and `reset()`?

Comment: You know the source code is freely available, and come with the JDK, right? Why don't you look? Why do you think FileInputStream is prevented from overriding these methods? It just **chooses** not to override them, because it's not **able** to implement them. You can't rewind a FileInputStream.

Comment: @JB Nizet I tried looking it up from this [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/io/FileInputStream.java) but I still didnt get anything. Let me go through the JDK since I didnt know about that.

Comment: The source code comes with the JDK. Control-click the FileInputStream class in your IDE, and you should see the source code in your IDE directly. mark() and reset() are implemented in InputStream, that FileInputStream extends.

Comment: Got it. The answer to the question also explained on the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can** override any protected or public, non-final method from any parent class:

```
class A extends FileInputStream {
    public A(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(file);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void mark(int readlimit) {
        super.mark(readlimit);
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        return super.skip(n);
    }
}
```

But I think I don't get your question right?

FileInputStream.reset() throws an IOException, because this class don't support mark and reset:

```
public synchronized void reset() throws IOException {
    throw new IOException("mark/reset not supported");
}
```

But the mark() **does not** throw an IOException:

```
public synchronized void mark(int readlimit) {}
```

This behaviour is also documented in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset--).

Comment: I was going through a Java guide where it was not explained why it throws an IOException. This is what led me to asking the question as my understanding was that you cannot override this two specific methods from `InputStream` class. Thanks and will read more from the source code.